# MS 365 Word - Display Character Location in Status Bar (or some where else)

Tags: microsoft-word

This is not a programming question but is driven by what I do in VBA. In VBA for Word, the Bookmark object has a .Start and .End property which gives the character location of the start and end of a bookmark in a Word document.

What I would like to do is display the equivalent character position of the cursor in the document say in the Word Status Bar (or somewhere else).

Right clicking on the Status Bar only gives the options to show location by Line Number, Column, Vertical Page Position etc. and not the character location as described above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding custom items to the status bar is not supported anymore. I think that went away after Office 2007 was introduced.

You might be able to do something with a custom task pane or a non-modal dialog. It will require the user to select the position and then click something on the task pane, dialog, or custom ribbon control.